# why page is reloading when html button executing c# code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I have html form which default value is display:none.
Im showing it with jquery.

There is button with C# code behind. When its executing page is reloading and my form is disappearing(display:none).
How i can execute c# code without page reload  ?

Comment: Hit the C# code using an ajax request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your c# code is server side and the page reloads to be able to call it. If you don't want that you'll need to use some AJAX.

See this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-make-client-side-network-callbacks-with-aspnet-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Is all of your code in the Page_Load section? Each time you make a callback the Page_Load runs. To stop certain things from happening each time you make a callback you can put them in something like

```
if (!Page.IsCallback && !Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //this code will only be run the first time the page is loaded.
}
```